# UIView behaving differently if added programmatically or with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I'm considering whether to programmatically add UI elements to my application or to use the Xcode's Storyboard. I noticed that in these two cases a UIView appears differently in the final application.

Here's the code if I add it programatically

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 705)];
// use the view (including adding subviews programmatically)
```

And here's the size inspector tab if I add it via Interface builder:

[image]

I create an outlet connection (calling the UIView "myView") and modify just the line of code I posted above in this way:

```
UIView *view = self.myView;
// use the view (including adding subviews programmatically)
```

However, the final result is slightly different. The Interface builder's UIView seems to be in a different position with respect to the one created programmatically. I don't think it matters, but I'm using modifying the UIView with [this pre-made class](https://github.com/BTLibrary/BTGlassScrollView).

Thank you for your help!

---

Here are the different results I get (the background is generated randomly, so don't mind if they're different). The UIView just appears to be in a different position. The label and the boxes are generated programmatically and added as subviews.

[image]

Comment: Could you show the "slighty different result"?

Comment: Probably due to Auto Layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I added some screenshots

Comment: I'll try and put some constraints now - I'll let you know.

Comment: It was auto-layout messing it up. I added some constraints and it displays without problems now. Thank you for everyone's help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was auto-layout messing it up. I added some constraints and it displays without problems now. Thank you for everyone's help :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using "this pre made class", i.e. BTGlassScrollView. But in your code you are saying:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 705)];
```

So you are getting a plain vanilla UIView - not a BTGlassScrollView.

Comment: I am using this instance of UIView and putting in a custom ScrollView through that custom class.